# python regex lookbehind to remove _sublabel1 in string like "__label__label1_sublabel1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re, python-3.10, python-regex

i have dataset that prepare for train in fasttext and i wanna remove sublabels from dataset
for example:

`__label__label1_sublabel1 __label__label2_sublabel1 __label__label3 __label__label1_sublabel4 sometext some sentce som data.`

Any help much appreciated
thanks

im tried this:

```
r'(?<=__label__[^_]+)\w+'
```

isnt working
exact code:

```
ptrn = r'(?<=__label__[^_]+)\w+'

re.sub(ptrn, '', test_String)
```

and this error was occured:
error:

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> c:\Users\THoseini\Desktop\projects\ensani_classification\tes4t.ipynb
> Cell 3 in <cell line: 3>()
> 1 ptrn = r'(?<=**label**[^_]+)\w+'
> ----> 3 re.sub(ptrn, '', test_String)
>
> File
> c:\Users\THoseini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py:209,
> in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
> 202 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
> 203     """Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
> 204     non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
> 205     replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
> 206     if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
> 207     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
> 208     a replacement string to be used."""
> --> 209     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
>
> File
> c:\Users\THoseini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py:303,
> in _compile(pattern, flags)
> 301 if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
> 302     raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
> --> 303 p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
> 304 if not (flags & DEBUG):
> 305     if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
> 306         # Drop the oldest item
>
> File
> c:\Users\THoseini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_compile.py:792,
> in compile(p, flags)
> --> 198         raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
> 199     emit(lo) # look behind
> 200 _compile(code, av[1], flags)
>
> error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this regex:

`(__label__[^_\s]+)\w*`

> after \w star instead of plus to avoid remove whole next label when label doesn't have sublabel

and a sample code in python:

```
import re
test_string = """__label__label1_sublabel1 __label__label2_sublabel1 __label__label3 __label__label1_sublabel4 sometext some sentce som data."""

ptrn = r'(__label__[^_\s]+)\w*'
re.sub(ptrn, r'\1', test_string)
```

The `re.sub()` function stands for a substring and returns a string with replaced values.
`[^character_group]` means negation: Matches any single character that is not in character_group. and `\w` matches any word character. `\s` matches any white-space character.

and output are like expected:

```
__label__label1 __label__label2 __label__label __label__label1 sometext some sentce som data.
```